# Third-person pronouns for inanimate objects in the next sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, pronouns

What pronoun to put for inanimate objects in a new sentence (he/she/they) or (it)?
For example:

*A rainbow appeared in the sky. She was very beautiful.*

or:

*A rainbow appeared in the sky. It was very beautiful.*

Or are both possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this link will answer your question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287721/pronoun-question-referring-to-inanimate-objects-as-he-or-she

Comment: I've never heard of a rainbow being personified (spoken of as though it were human).

Comment: @RubioRic Yes, that seems to be what I need. Thanks you!

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks you! I understood.

Comment: The sun can be personified. Cars can be personified (using he or she, depending on the person and the car). Ships with names are usually personified as female, even ships with male names. Rainbow? Never heard that.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thank you for the interesting examples!

Comment: Note that you can apply a gender to anything in the right context. Using *she* in the sentences in the question is strange. But if those two sentences were at the start of an actual ***story***, where the rainbow spoke, took actions, and had thoughts, then it would be entirely appropriate. (Of course, in the context of such a story, the rainbow would no longer be considered an *inanimate object* …)

Comment: @Jason Bassford Many thanks! Now I understand.